# jQuery take value for input[type ="text"] in jQuery data with defined variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have my markup like this. Now here you can see every button has same class named button.

```
  <div class="cart">
    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="12" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="42" />
    &nbsp;<input type="button" value="add to cart" class="button-cart" class="button" />
  </div>

  <div class="cart">
    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="132" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="42" />
    &nbsp;<input type="button" value="add to cart" class="button-cart" class="button" />
  </div>

  <div class="cart">
    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="135" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="42" />
    &nbsp;<input type="button" value="add to cart" class="button-cart" class="button" />
  </div>
```

Here is my jQuery script

```
 jQuery('.button-cart').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).live('click',function() {
    console.log(jQuery(this));
    var s= jQuery(this).siblings('input[type="text"]');
    console.log(s);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'],.product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                //$('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
                setTimeout(opencartpage(),1000);
            }   
        }
    });  
  });
})
```

Now here you can see in `jQuery data .product-info input[type=\'text\']` is defined. In that place  it is taking the data for all the `input type text data`. In the same way I want to define  `jQuery(this).siblings('input[type="text"]')` which will take the input value for only selected button at that time for this I am using `this` inside class cart in ajax data .So can some one tell me how to do this?

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to use a *selector* with `live` and not just a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with Add to Cart button functionality. 
The problem can be easily resolved via.

[Click Here For Solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156468/opencart-when-adding-to-cart-the-item-returns-error-even-though-options-are-sele)