# Opencart when adding to cart the item returns error even though options are selected

Tags: php, forms, opencart

I made a quick template for the opencart php shopping cart engine. I am having problems adding items to the cart, because it is showing that the option was not selected, but it clearly was, so I guess I am missing something in the template, but I can not seem to find what's missing.

Code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6807794

Thank you, it will be huge help, if someone can point out the thing. (:

Comment: I doubt somebody will go through all the code or list in Your GH directory... Please, show us some *problem understanding* and point out the part of the code (by posting it here) where the error may occur. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the jquery add to cart function at the bottom `(line 218)`.

```
    data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
```

You removed the class `product-info` from a div `(Line 20)` and replaced it with an id of `item-info`. Because of that, jQuery cannot find the selectboxes (nor any other element) to post.

Either
1) Change your HTML to use `product-info` again (best option)
2) Update all the JS that refers to `.product-info` to `#item-info`

You would be best with the first option though, as there could be multiple JS code refering to `.product-info`